# How to associate the json data to flutter list?

Tags: json, flutter, flutter-listview

I am able to fetch the json data in flutter applicaion.
Now I want to associate that data with the `List`.

How should I do that?

```
List companydetails;

var jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
```

JSON DATA

```
 {"error":"false","content":[
{
"id":"22","name":"Johnny",},

{"id":"23","name":"Maria",},
]
}
```

I need to build a list view in flutter from the fetched data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this model:

```
class CompanyDetail {
  String error;
  List<Content> content;

  CompanyDetail({this.error, this.content});

  CompanyDetail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    error = json['error'];
    if (json['content'] != null) {
      content = new List<Content>();
      json['content'].forEach((v) {
        content.add(new Content.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['error'] = this.error;
    if (this.content != null) {
      data['content'] = this.content.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Content {
  String id;
  String name;

  Content({this.id, this.name});

  Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Then bind the Json data:

```
var companyDetail = CompanyDetail.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
```

Now use Content List in your ListView widget:

```
companyDetail.content
```

Example (make sure that `content` is not null):

```
....
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: companyDetail.content.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return new Text(companyDetail.content[index]);
    }
  ),
...
```

Comment: I am new to this api learning flutter. how would i access the elements in list view builder in `companyDetail.content`, please guide